# Auth0 - OAuth login with dynamic callback

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I want to secure my Web-App with Auth0 in React. This means a user can login on my page and use the resulting Access Token to make requests to services behind AWS API Gateway.

But Auth0 requires that all possible Callback URLs are defined in the Dashboard.
This works well as long as the Application is hosted on a domain owned by me.

In my case the React App will be distributed as a Plugin (Shopify, Woocommerce). My users will install this Plugin and use my App through their shopsystem-UI. Which means that requests from the browser are made from their domain.

How should I securely access my Services through this client which is distributed on Domains which i don't know beforehead?

As my research shows, one solution would be [Dynamic Application Registration](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/dynamic-client-registration). But with this I would end up with one Auth0 Application per user and Auth0 Limits that to 100 Applications.

How should I handle my case instead?

Comment: It sounds really funny (to me, I think) that you would expect your users (devs) to use your plugin and have their users routed through your auth0 account. I'm probably misunderstanding something. It sounds like your plugin should allow users to enter their own auth0 configuration? If what I am saying sounds wrong to you, maybe provide some more context about what your plugin does.

Comment: I want to create a platform where users can login (with Auth0) and make some changes to their settings. For example users may select specific Products from their shopsystem. Those Products will be displayed to the consumers of my platform. The problem is that I'm unable to authenticate users through plugins in their shopsystems (which is needed for UX) because of unknown domain.